# How to import in to laravel via npm jquery-ui-datepicker-with-i18n?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, npm

I'm new using npm and I have installed in my project the package jquery-ui-datepicker-with-i18n when I import it on my project it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` but I have jquery installed.

Here is my bootstrap.js:

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.jQueryUI = require('jquery-ui');
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

here is my app.js:

```
require('../bootstrap');

try {
    window.daterangepicker = require('daterangepicker');
    window.moment = require('moment');
    window.dragscroll = require('dragscroll');
} catch (e) {}


import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css';
import 'jquery-ui-datepicker-with-i18n/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js';
```

I execute npm run dev and all compile fine but then I get the error without even calling this line:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
```

Package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.1.4",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.23.7",
        "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "daterangepicker": "^3.0.5",
        "dragscroll": "0.0.8",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "jquery-ui-datepicker-with-i18n": "^1.10.4",
        "moment": "^2.24.0"
    }
}
```

How should I use and import jquery-ui-datepicker-with-i18n? what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the `datepicker` plugin itself before you import the language. Try it like this:

```
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css';
// Add this line before the i18n language
import 'jquery-ui-datepicker-with-i18n/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js';
import 'jquery-ui-datepicker-with-i18n/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js';
```

**EDIT**

Now I see you're importing the widget directly from `jquery-ui`, so, you'll have to use the language file included in `jquery-ui` package. Try it like this without using the `jquery.ui.datepicker`:

```
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/i18n/datepicker-es.js';
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css';
```

Comment: thanks it worked, so jquery-ui alredy had everything installed even the i18n? so install the package "jquery-ui-datepicker-with-i18n" was useless right?

Comment: @Cristian yes there is everything inside `jquery-ui`. I think they have `jquery-ui-datepicker-with-i18n` for cases when `jquery-ui` is imported with other ways and just want to attach the widget, but that also does not make a lot of sense.